# Alfresco Document Management supportive of all file types?

Tags: document, alfresco, document-management, dms

Quick question....

We're trying to make a decision on a dms here and Alfresco has been recommended to us.

Is the Alfresco Document Management supportive of all file types?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean what file types can be uploaded into Alfresco ?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, apologies for the poor explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can upload any kind of files into Alfresco.

If you upload a file called "muhammad.ali" using a strange file format, Alfresco will accept it with no problem, and you will be able to play with its meta-data etc like any other file. You probably will not be able to search for its content, though.

Comment: But alfresco (default instalation) will try to index it, though.

Comment: If you had a Java library that knew how to extract the indexable text from .ali files you could easily define the new file type and associate it with your custom class that does the extraction which would make files of the new type searchable.